# Interesting JavaScript inheritance pattern

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I have recently watched a video where [Douglas Crockford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) was explaining inheritance patterns of Javascript. The video itself is pretty old - it was filmed 6 years ago - but still useful. In that video he showed one inheritance pattern he kinda invented (although I am not sure who the author is). This is the code using his approach:

```js
// imitation of new operator
function objectConstructor(obj, initializer, methods) {
    // create prototype
    var func, prototype = Object.create(obj && obj.prototype);
    // add methods to the prototype
    if(methods) Object.keys(methods).forEach(function(key) {
        prototype[key] = methods[key];
    });
    // function that will create objects with prototype defined above
    func = function() {
        var that = Object.create(prototype);
        if(typeof initializer === 'function') initializer.apply(that, arguments);
        return that;
    }
    
    func.prototype = prototype;
    prototype.constructor = func;
    return func;
}

var person = objectConstructor(Object, function(name) {
    this.name = name;
},  {
    showName: function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
});
var employee = objectConstructor(person, function(name, profession) {
    this.name = name;
    this.profession = profession;
},  {
    showProfession: function() {
        console.log(this.profession);
    }
});
var employeeInfo = employee('Mike', 'Driver');
employeeInfo.showName(); // Mike
employeeInfo.showProfession(); // Driver
```

Unfortanately, he didn't show the invocation. So, this part

```
var employeeInfo = employee('Mike', 'Driver');
employeeInfo.showName();
employeeInfo.showProfession();
```

is mine. It generally works, but it turns out that I repeat `this.name = name;` for both "classes" - `person` and `employee`. I played around but I didn't manage to make it work properly without that repetition. Seems I cannot get `name` because such a property isn't contained in the prototypal chain for `employee`. I didn't succeed either in mixing in stuff like `person.call(this, arguments)`. So, apart from whether it is cool/nice/smart/sensible etc. or not in 2017, how could I remove `this.name = name;` from `employee` and get the same result? Or everything is ok and this approach doesn't suppose it?

Comment: `var employeeInfo = new employee('Mike', 'Driver');`  don't forget the `new`

Comment: hehe the whole trick is to imitate new :)

Comment: No, I think the whole point is to create an inheritance pattern, not to get rid of new..  If you want to get rid of new, there is something called the factory pattern..  Try putting new on two employee's, and you will see it works.

Comment: yes, to create an inheritance pattern but without new. I mean new is not the point here. It generally works without it. Adding new here doesn't affect anything since the function returns its own object `that` with prototype set, not the newly created one.

Comment: Ah, right see now.   So your question is how would you say do  `super(name)` using this approach?.

Comment: yeah. In order to avoid repeating `this.name = name` and potentially a larger set of parameters in several places. If I added `name` to `person` it would become invisible for `employee` since `emloyee`'s __proto__ points to `person`'s prototype, not the `person` itself. So, I need to call `person` somehow and pass in `emoloyee` context. But when and where?

Comment: I'm not sure this code is right, he is storing a constructor on the prototype, but also creating the object inside the constructor, I've no idea why you would expose this.  With some small mod's I can do a kind of `super(name)`,  but instead of storing `func` on the constructor, I store the `initializer`.   I can post a snippet as answer if that is of any use..

Comment: yes, I would like to take a look. That's just an approach I came across watching a video. Personally, I prefer more widespread technique called "classical" or "pseudoclassical".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your snippet with 2 small modifications so that you can do a super(name) type of call.

I've placed comments were I've made the modifications.. with prefix keith:

```js
// imitation of new operator
function objectConstructor(obj, initializer, methods) {
    // create prototype
    var func, prototype = Object.create(obj && obj.prototype);
    // add methods to the prototype
    if(methods) Object.keys(methods).forEach(function(key) {
        prototype[key] = methods[key];
    });
    // function that will create objects with prototype defined above
    func = function() {
        var that = Object.create(prototype);
        if(typeof initializer === 'function') initializer.apply(that, arguments);
        return that;
    }
    
    func.prototype = prototype;
    //keith: store the initialization in constructor,
    //keith: as func is already creating the object..
    prototype.constructor = initializer;
    return func;
}

var person = objectConstructor(Object, function(name) {
    this.name = name;
},  {
    showName: function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
});
var employee = objectConstructor(person, function(name, profession) {
    //keith: call our super  person(name)
    person.prototype.constructor.call(this, name);
    this.profession = profession;
},  {
    showProfession: function() {
        console.log(this.profession);
    }
});
var employeeInfo = employee('Mike', 'Driver');
employeeInfo.showName(); // Mike
employeeInfo.showProfession(); // Driver
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `func` *constructor* completely disregards `this`, passing any context to it via `call` or `apply` will not work. Creating a way to copy over the *super* class' properties after creating an object is one of the ways you could accomplish your task.

```js
// imitation of new operator
function objectConstructor(obj, initializer, methods) {
    // create prototype
    var func, prototype = Object.create(obj && obj.prototype);
    // add methods to the prototype
    if(methods) Object.keys(methods).forEach(function(key) {
        prototype[key] = methods[key];
    });
    // function that will create objects with prototype defined above
    func = function() {
        var that = Object.create(prototype);
        if(typeof initializer === 'function') initializer.apply(that, arguments);
        return that;
    }
    
    func.prototype = prototype;
    prototype.constructor = func;
    return func;
}

function copyProperties(source, target) {
  for (var prop in source) {
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      target[prop] = source[prop];
    }
  }
}

var person = objectConstructor(Object, function(name) {
    this.name = name;
},  {
    showName: function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
});
var employee = objectConstructor(person, function(name, profession) {
    copyProperties(person.apply(null, arguments), this);
    this.profession = profession;
},  {
    showProfession: function() {
        console.log(this.profession);
    }
});
var employeeInfo = employee('Mike', 'Driver');
employeeInfo.showName(); // Mike
employeeInfo.showProfession(); // Driver
```